# Countable additivity condition

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu_n, n\ge1$ be a sequence of measure on a measurable space $(X,M)$. Suppose there exists a number $c>0$ such that $\nu_n \le c$ for all $n\ge 1$. Define a set function $\nu$ by 
$$\nu(E)=\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\nu_n(E)}{2^n}$$ for all $E\in M$.

My question:- I want to know if $\nu$ satisfy the countable additivity condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any non-negative sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ we have that
$$
\nu(E):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \nu_n(E),\quad E\in M,
$$
defines a finite measure on $(X,M)$. In particular, $\nu$ satisfies the countable additivity condition.

Proof: Clearly $\nu(E)\geq 0$ for all $E\in M$ and $\nu(\varnothing)=0$. Moreover, 
$$
\nu(E)\leq \nu(X)\leq c\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty
$$
showing that $\nu$ is finite. Now, let $(E_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be a countable collection of disjoint sets from $M$. Then
$$
\nu\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\Big)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\nu_n\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\Big)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \nu_n(E_k)\Big).
$$
Since this is a double sum of non-negative terms we may interchange the two sums
$$
\nu\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\Big)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \nu_n(E_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\nu(E_k)
$$
which shows that $\nu$ satisfies the countable additivity condition.

Comment: thanks.. its so detailed and help me a lot .

Comment: One question; did the summation in the first row of your answer should be from 1 to $n$ or from 1 to $\infty$ .

Comment: Should be the latter. Thanks for catching the mistake.